# how to get # of files copied using rsync

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, rsync

I'm using rsync in a script (on OSX) to copy from a raid to 2 backup drives, which happens when  I run the script, probably 10x-20x in a day.  I'm trying to figure out a way to parse the rsync log file, or anything for that matter, to tell me the number of files that were copied.  Here is my rsync command:

```
rsync -auvh --delete --progress "$SourceTx" "$Dest1Tx" --log file="$SourceRoot/""CopyLog1.txt"
```

and my attempt (not working) to grep the log-file to derive the # of files copied:

```
cd "$SourceRoot/"
howMany=$(cat CopyLog1.txt | grep -c .mov)
osascript -e 'display notification "Transcode Copy Complete, '$howMany' files transfered, Log Files Created" with title "Transcode Copy Script"'
```

Answer (score 9):

To get the number of files transferred, use the `--stats` option. For example:

```
$ rsync -auvh --stats --delete --log-file=1.log --progress "$SourceTx" "$Dest1Tx" | grep 'files transferred'
Number of regular files transferred: 21
```

To capture the number of files transferred to a shell variable:

```
nfiles=$(rsync -auvh --stats --delete --log-file=1.log --progress "$SourceTx" "$Dest1Tx" | awk '/files transferred/{print $NF}')
```

The above was filtered to just show the number of files transferred.  To illustrate the other information available with `--stats`:

```
$ rsync -auh --stats --delete  srcdir destdir

Number of files: 14 (reg: 10, dir: 4)
Number of created files: 0
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 0
Total file size: 209 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 0
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 342
Total bytes received: 27

sent 342 bytes  received 27 bytes  738.00 bytes/sec
total size is 209  speedup is 0.57
```

Comment: this line:   nfiles=$(rsync -auvh --stats --delete --log-file=1.log --progress "$SourceTx" "$Dest1Tx" | awk '/files transferred/{print $NF}')                                runs rsync and then stores the number of files transferred into the variable nfiles correct?  So in my notification I would just call $nfiles and be done?                         Also, if I call --stats, will this print in the log file?  Thanks btw.  much appreciated.

Comment: @borneo1910 Yes,  `nfiles` would have the number of files transferred and you can use that later in the script has you like.  (Technically, you don't "call it" because it is not a function or executable; it is just a variable with a value.)  Also, yes, the stats information appears in the log file.

Comment: I lost the progress output, ie % copied per file and data rate, etc.  is there a way to get that back?

Comment: If you still want to see all the progress information, add a `tee` command.  For example: `nfiles=$(rsync -auvh --stats --delete --log-file=1.log --progress "$SourceTx" "$Dest1Tx" | tee /dev/stderr | awk '/files transferred/{print $NF}')`

Comment: Ok that works very well, but now here's a question.  Something slowed down the transfer considerably.  Drag and drop is about 10x faster.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, I'm copying to 2 locations, so I have the same command, one right after the other, going to a different location obviously.  When I use an & after the first command, I loose the first $nfiles in my notification.  but when I don't use the ampersand, it copies sequentially and not in parallel, which is what I want.

Comment: @borneo1910 Hmm, slow is not good.  To start, let's distinguish two things: (a) the speed of file transfer, and (b) the speed of the output display.  Adding `tee` adds more I/O buffers and could very easily slow down the output display.  But, I don't see any way that adding `tee` could change the file transfer speed.  I suspect that something else unrelated is going on: a CPU is busy, the network is busy, something like that.

Comment: First off, I owe you some beers or a bottle of whiskey or something.  I ran my old rsync command and it was still just as slow.  I've reformatted the destination drives and will be able to launch a copy in about 15-20m and will report back.  Also, my CPU is not anywhere near taxed while copying, it was like 98% idle.  Will report back soon.

Comment: Reformatting the drives as HFS+ didn't do anything

Comment: destination drives connected via 6G esata (Atto H680 in PCIe Slot) and Raid (Source) is a 8TB SSD Raid connected via 12G SAS to an Areca Raid Card.  All speed tests show bandwidth isn't a problem and I wasn't doing anything else when I was using the script.

Comment: Is rsync reporting good transfer speeds?  How sure are you of the speed of drag-and-drop?  I suspect that drag-and-drop just schedules to transfer to occur in the background which might take much longer than it appears in the interface.

Comment: Pretty sure of the speed.  Using Path finder, which gives you the transfer speed, ie >250MB/s to each GRAID drive.  That also correlates to the speed test I'm running and when I run: time dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024k of=tstfile count=1024 2>&1 | awk '/sec/ {print $1 / $5 / 1048576, "MB/sec" }'   I get like 400MB/s (which probably isn't too accurate since the drives shouldn't actually go that fast..  I'll post my entire script above.

Comment: updating rsync seemed to do the trick!!  I still owe you big time.  thanks so much.  But the nfiles nor reporting when I use the & after the command is still an issue.  any thoughts on that?